# ResumeThread doesn't work after attaching to the process using vTrace

Tags: python

In an effort to learn vtrace I've been trying to attach to a process and hook the import address table and then resume the main thread of a process.  When I don't attach to the process the ResumeThread() call works fine.  But when I do it spins up a thread then the call to ResumeThread() doesn't work and the main thread never runs.  Below is the code...

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes
from defines import *
import vdb
import vtrace
import sys
from iathook import *

class PROCESS_INFORMATION(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("hProcess",    HANDLE),
            ("hThread",     HANDLE),
            ("dwProcessId", DWORD),
            ("dwThreadId",  DWORD),
            ]    

process_info    = PROCESS_INFORMATION()

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32.dll')

bCreateProcessW = kernel32.CreateProcessA(
                                path_to_binary,
                                None,
                                None,
                                None,
                                True,
                                creation_flags,
                                None,
                                None,
                                byref(startupinfo),
                                byref(process_info))

#launched the process in a suspended state and patch it using DLL injection
#but this code doesn't effect the following code

apptrace = vtrace.getTrace()              
apptrace.attach(process_info.dwProcessId)     #1
hookSomeStuff = hookIat(apptrace, 'MSVCR110') #2
#apptrace.resumeThread(process_info.hThread)  #3
dwPrevSuspendCount = kernel32.ResumeThread(process_info.hThread)
```

As I mentioned above when I remove the `vtrace attach` and and `hookIat` stuff (line #1 & #2).  The ResumeThread() call works fine and the main thread runs.  I also tried resuming the thread using the vtrace method (line #3) but it tells me that the thread is not suspended.  The main thread doesn't actually run so I wonder how it could not be suspended or what happened to it.  I also check the events of the binary using procmon and when it attaches it spins up another thread and that seems to throw things off.  This may seem awkward and I understand there are many other ways to do this but I'm using it as a learning exercise and now I'm interested why it's not working.  Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance for any help.